# Javascript regexp: replacing $1 with f($1)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, idioms

I have a regular expression, say `/url.com\/([A-Za-z]+)\.html/`, and I would like to replace it with `new string $1: f($1)`, that is, with a constant string with two interpolations, the captured string and a function of the captured string.

What's the best way to do this in JavaScript?  'Best' here means some combination of (1) least error-prone, (2) most efficient in terms of space and speed, and (3) most idiomatically appropriate for JavaScript, with a particular emphasis on #3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `replace` method can [take a function as the replacement parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

For example:

```
str.replace(/regex/, function(match, group1, group2, index, original) { 
    return "new string " + group1 + ": " + f(group1);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

When using `String.replace`, you can [supply a callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) as the replacement parameter instead of a string and create your own, very custom return value.

```
'foo'.replace(/bar/, function (str, p1, p2) {
    return /* some custom string */;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) takes a function for the replace, like this:

```
var newStr = string.replace(/url.com\/([A-Za-z]+)\.html/, function(all, match) {
  return match + " something";
});
```

You can transform the result however you want, just return whatever you want the match to be in that callback.  [You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/UqWgm/).